# In the controller do a find specifiing basic conditions but the query built by cakephp doesn't match the conditions

Tags: mysql, cakephp, find

In the controller :

```
$budget = $this->Budget->find('first',
        array('conditions' => array(
                "copros_id" => $this->Session->read('Copro.id'),
                "typebudgets_id" => $typebudget['Typebudget']['id'],
                "exercices_id" => $this->Session->read('Exercice.id'))));
```

generates the sql:

```
SELECT `Budget`.`id`, 
       `Budget`.`created`, 
       `Budget`.`modified`, 
       `Budget`.`title`, 
       `Budget`.`statusbudgets_id`, 
       `Budget`.`typebudgets_id`, 
       `Budget`.`copros_id`, 
       `Budget`.`visible`, 
       `Budget`.`exercices_id` 
FROM `default_schema`.`budgets` AS `Budget` 
WHERE `Budget`.`typebudgets_id` = ('466b50a5-4736-11e6-a160-00163ee3b504')
```

The Model contains :

```
public $belongsTo = array(
  'StatusBudget' => array(
    'className' => 'StatusBudget',
    'foreignKey' => 'statusbudgets_id'
   ),   
  'Exercice' => array(
    'className' => 'Exercice',
    'foreignKey' => 'exercices_id'
   ),
  'Typebudget' => array(
    'className' => 'Typebudget',
    'foreignKey' => 'typebudgets_id'
   ),   
  'Copro' => array(
    'className' => 'Copro',
    'foreignKey' => 'copros_id'
   ),   
);
```

It looks like the conditions in the find are ignored by cakephp (2) when building the query; specifying different conditions in the find give the same sql as a result. As if the conditions don't matter in fact.
Strange (for me).
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things may be happening here:

1. First try to clear the model cache. If you don't know how to use the cake console just delete the files in the /tmp/cache/model folders.
2. The table behind the `Budget` model does NOT have the columns you are making a reference to. Or there is a typo in their name. In that case Cake will not use them when you build your conditions.
3. The db table for `budget` has all the required columns, but the way the Table **class** is defined could interfere with properly reading the table structure from the database.

Comment: thank you for taking time:
1/ model cache cleared
2/ don't see problem with columns in  table Budget :
CREATE TABLE `budgets` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `statusbudgets_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `typebudgets_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `copros_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `visible` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exercices_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
3/ "the way the Table class  is defined": can't figure out exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about Ilia Pandia's answer I tried to specify more precisly my conditions:

```
   $budget = $this->Budget->find('first',
            array('conditions' => array(
                    "Budget.copros_id" => $this->Session->read('Copro.id'),
                    "Budget.typebudgets_id" => $typebudget['Typebudget']['id'],
                    "Budget.exercices_id" => $this->Session>read('Exercice.id'))));
```

The sql generated is now what I expected:

```
SELECT `Budget`.`id`, ... 
FROM `default_schema`.`budgets` AS `Budget` 
  LEFT JOIN `default_schema`.`status_budgets` AS `StatusBudget` ON (`Budget`.`statusbudgets_id` = `StatusBudget`.`id`) 
  LEFT JOIN `default_schema`.`exercices` AS `Exercice` ON (`Budget`.`exercices_id` = `Exercice`.`id`) 
  LEFT JOIN `default_schema`.`typebudgets` AS `Typebudget` ON (`Budget`.`typebudgets_id` = `Typebudget`.`id`) 
  LEFT JOIN `default_schema`.`copros` AS `Copro` ON (`Budget`.`copros_id` = `Copro`.`id`)
```

WHERE `Budget`.`copros_id` = '5af2bda8-97d0-403a-ad96-4cf1ac171864' 
AND `Budget`.`typebudgets_id` = '466b50a5-4736-11e6-a160-00163ee3b504' 
AND `Budget`.`exercices_id` = '5af2c13b-43d0-412f-97d9-4752ac171864' LIMIT 1

Thank you!